# fish_add_path not working for flutter SDK; results in permission denied to open universal variable file

Tags: flutter, path, fish, iterm2

I am trying to append the path variable for the flutter binary SDK on the fish shell and keeps running into errors upon running `fish_add_path -U /flutter/bin` I moved it into my $HOME which is `/Users/daleyu`. When I add the path variable, it is able to work and run `which flutter` and run flutter commands but it won't save when I reload the terminal session.

Also, it results in the lines `error: Unable to open universal variable file '/': Permission denied`. This will print after every command that I run. I have tried looked at other posts and at the fish github issues page and they didn't seem to have a solution.

Information:

- I am running fish 3.5.1
- Intel Macbook air chip
- I am using iterm2 as my terminal

Here is a picture outlining the issue:
[iterm session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jwa3B.png)

Any help is really appreciated, thank you!

I've watched some setup guides and followed along, and it seemed to work fine with zsh, but not with fish. I've tried like setting up my $XDG_CACHE_HOME, and such because I saw it in another online thread but only to no luck.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you tried $XDG_**CONFIG**_HOME? That's the directory where the universal variable file is stored.

Comment: Hey Faho, I saw that online and I was not sure how to modify it. I did echo $XDG_CONFIG_HOME, and it returned an empty line. If you could help me understand what that is then that would be much appreciated.

Comment: The directory fish uses for the universal variable file (where it stores universal variables) is $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/fish if that variable is set, or $HOME/.config/fish if it isn't. It appears you might have set an empty $XDG_CONFIG_HOME (instead of not setting it at all). $XDG_CACHE_HOME has no relevance here. You'll have to set it in fish's parent process, e.g. your terminal.

Comment: (you can't set it inside of fish because it's also where fish finds its config in general - config.fish is at $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/fish/config.fish)

Comment: I will go about trying to set that now, but I read that it should only be set when I want to override it. Is that okay? Should I just reinstall fish? Could that correct the issue? Thank you for all your help

Comment: Yes, you should only set it if you want to override it. However, in your case it appears to have already been set *for you*, by something in your configuration, like your terminal or your system configuration (the IntelliJ included terminals will for example set it, as will typical terminal "shell integration" scripts). No, I do not believe reinstalling fish would be helpful.

Comment: I ended up upgrading my fish version to the latest stable release, and it ended up fixing the $XDG_CONFIG_HOME variable automatically. That fixed my problem, and flutter was able to be added as a path variable. Thank you for your help!